# iOS 12 : Camera access request dialog box shows default permission

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, ios12

Our ios App is running fine upto ios 11, built on ionic 3 framework.

The only problem we are facing is above 12.0.1.

Camera Access Permission Popup **shows default** "Request Permission Message" rather than Custom Permission added by us.

We have already added NSCamera Permissions and it is working fine upto ios11. **This issue is only coming in ios12.0.1 and above**.

Need help resolving this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Raj

Comment: where you are adding camera permission description ?

Comment: are you adding in config.xml?

Comment: Yes. we are adding permissions in config.xml

Comment: <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
        <string>xxx description</string>
    </edit-config>

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your camera plugin and add again. Here are the steps/commands to execute:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm camera
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera  --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message" --variable PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

Comment: i added cordova plugins and variables with messages. Buy does not seems to be working on ipad running on 12.0.1 and above.